# mvc asp.net web project first load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I published My Web project that written by C# MVC5 ASP.NET and Entity framework on a Shared Host. First Time that it loads, speed is very slow and take a long time almost 12 second but after that it is ok . I tested my website on a gtmetrix.com and fortunately is in A class.Could anyone tell me why it takes a long time for first load ?I have some suggestion.
 1)it because of entity framework ?
 2)it because of a lot of library that I used them and it needs to load these dll files before load ?
 3)I need some config in IIs (I dont access to IIs Server because Im using      shared host)?
(also compilation debug is false)
I am appreciated If some one help me . 
web site address is www.kajalmarket.com and is uploaded most recently .

Comment: The first time a .net site is 'Hit' in IIS, IIS will compile the site. So even though you are publishing your site pre-compiled, IIS will not compile it until the first person hits it.

Comment: Thanks for Comment. So you think it is natural and i should not worry about that and I could not do anything.

Comment: If it just affects the first person to hit the page, i wouldnt worry about it. If it is noticeable across different clients and different times then I would investigate.

Comment: The interest thing that I found out about that is When There are at least 2 online number on website the speed is ok! but when it decrease to 1 user it takes long time to load for some on that open the website .maybe web server sleep !!!!.

Answer (score 0):

You can precompile prior to deployment if you're concerned.

Here's more info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227972(v=vs.90).aspx

> Precompiling an ASP.NET Web site provides faster initial response time for users since pages do not have to be compiled the first time they are requested. This is particularly useful for large Web sites that are updated frequently.

You can also select "Precompile during publishing" if you publish via Visual Studio:
[Click here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xJ23.png).

Another option is as follows taken from ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx ):

> If you want to be able to change top-level files without causing the whole site to be recompiled, you can set the optimizeCompilations attribute of the compilation element in the Web.config file to true. If optimizeCompilations is true, when you change a top-level file only the affected files are recompiled. This saves time but can cause run-time errors depending on the type of changes you make to a top-level file.

With this method you should see a reduced re-compilation time as it only recompiles those top level files that have changed.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for answer wazdev I did Precompilation  but It is like before .

Comment: There's also a flag you can switch off that prevents full recompilation. I've updated my answer accordingly.